# UIImageVIew crash when CIFiltered UIImage setted

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, cifilter

I'm trying to "CIFiltering" some images.
But UIImageView crash when putting filtered uiimage.
I've never seen this situation and don't know next step to how figure out.
Please help or teach some tips. Thank you.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/simulating_scratchy_analog_film

[image]
This is what happens.

Comment: While a good answer, the *reason* was rather poorly explained. (Apple docs can be cryptic sometimes.) A `CIImage` isn't an image, but rather a *recipe* for producing an image. You can take a CIImage and turn it into a `UIImage` or `CGImage` (UI == UIKit, CG == CoreGraphics) of basically any size/extent you wish, but usually you keep the ratio intact. It may be you were also facing another issue that the accepted answer helped out on - turning a CIImage into a UIImage through using COreGraphics or a CGImage. It's rather obscured in the docs, but unless you create that CGImage you'll get SIGABRT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do the following changes in the function :

At the beginning of the function add :

```
public func filter(_image) {
    let aUIImage     = _image

    guard let aCGImage = aUIImage.cgImage else { return }
    let aCIImage       = CIImage(cgImage: aCGImage)
    let context        = CIContext(options: nil)
```

and replace this line `let image = UIImage(ciImage: speckledImage)` with :

```
let imageRef = context.createCGImage(speckledImage, from: aCIImage.extent)
let image    = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)
```

**Reason :**

> You are creating an CIImage and trying to attach it to UIImageView which is not possible. According to apple docs : `Although a CIImage object has image data associated with it, it is not an image.`

Refer this link for more information : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage